# Como passar lista de checkboxes para ActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html5

Preciso saber como passar os valores dos *inputs* `checkboxes` para a *action* `Edit`, preciso passar as propriedades `Checked` e `Id` e armazenar em uma lista do tipo `Photo`. Ressaltando que o *controller* que esta sendo executado não é do mesmo tipo que a *view*, este controle é da `gallery`, o *model* `gallery` possui uma propriedade do tipo `List<Photo>`.

Segue abaixo os *prints*.

*Model*:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*View*:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*Controller*:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*Print* da tela para entender o contexto:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Onde estão as CheckBoxes?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez atualizei a pergunta com o print do contexto geral.

Comment: O que estás a querer fazer subverte o padrão MVC. O controlador nunca vê a vista mas sim o contrário.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Faça seus checkboxes ficarem assim:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="photoToDeleteIds" value="@imagePath.IdPhoto" />
```

E altere a action do seu controller, adicionando um parâmetro `photoToDeleteIds`:

```
public ActionResult Edit(Gallery gallery, int[] photoToDeleteIds)
{
    // agora o parâmetro photoToDeleteIds contém os IDs das fotos que foram selecionadas
}
```

Ou então, altere a classe `Gallery`, incluindo uma propriedade `PhotoToDeleteIds`:

```
class Gallery
{
    public int[] PhotoToDeleteIds { get; set; }
    // ... restante da classe
}
```

Observe que existe correspondência entre os nomes do `input` e do parâmetro ou propriedade, dependendo do caminho que você escolher. Essa correspondência não é sensível à maiúscular/minúsculas.

Comment: perfeito, funcionou! :D

Comment: Esta funcionando perfeitamente esta parte mas gostaria de saber por que o parâmentro do tipo Gallery que a action recebe, esta só com ID e Title preenchidos...

Comment: Já descobri, pois teria que por um halper HiddenFor para poder passar como parâmetro :)