# Como criar uma View para esse caso de Modelo?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Estive tentando aplicar a solução dessa questão ([Como passar lista de checkboxes para ActionResult](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9982/como-passar-lista-de-checkboxes-para-actionresult-asp-net-mvc-c/9984#9984)) em um problema que estou tendo porém não estou conseguindo obter um resultado positivo.

Estou recebendo um array com várions **on's** em vez de receber um array com os **id's**, como imaginei que fosse ser.

Tenho as seguintes classes:

`Controle`:

```c-sharp
public class Controle
{
    public Controle() {
        Actions = new List<Action>();
    }
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]    
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Acao> Acoes { get; set; }
}
```

`Acao`:

```c-sharp
public class Acao
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ControleId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ControleId")]
    public Controle Controle { get; set; }
}
```

`Grupo`, que representaria os grupos em que os usuários estão alocados:

```c-sharp
public class Grupo
{
    public Grupo() {
        Acessos = new List<GrupoAcesso>();
    }
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Grupo")]
    public virtual List<GrupoAcesso> Acessos { get; set; }
}
```

E `GrupoAcesso`, que representa os `Controles` e `Acoes` que o Grupo tem acesso:

```c-sharp
public class GrupoAcesso
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int GrupoId { get; set; }
    public int ControleId { get; set; }
    public int AcaoId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("GrupoId")]
    public virtual Grupo Grupo { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ControleId")]
    public virtual Controle Controle { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("AcaoId")]
    public virtual Acao Acao { get; set; }
}
```

Até então estou tentando criar uma view que me apresente algo como:

[image: Exemplo de View]

Para listar as `Acoes` estou fazendo dessa forma:

```razor
@model Domain.Grupo
....
@{
    var checkeds = new string[] { };
    if (ViewBag.Checkeds != null) {
        checkeds = ViewBag.Checkeds as string[];
    }
}
...
<table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-bordered" style="margin:2px;">
    @for (var X = 0; X < controle.Acoes.Count(); X++)
    {
        var acao= controle.Acoes[X];
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label style="font-weight:bold; color:darkblue">@acao.Name</label>
            </td>
            <td class="text-center" style="width:50px; padding:0; vertical-align:middle;">
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkeds" id="@acao.Id"
                            if (checkeds.Contains(acao.Id.ToString())) { <text> checked </text> } />
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
...
```

Mas em meu método que recebo o **post**, o resultado desse "jogo" feito com os **checkboxes** está retornando uma lista de **on's** em vez de uma lista de **Id's**.

Meu método, que ainda não está completo, estou testando ainda:

```c-sharp
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Gravar([Bind(Exclude = "Acessos, Usuarios")]Domain.Grupo obj, string[] checkeds)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            // carrego o grupo caso ele já exista
            var rec = repository.Grupos.Include("Acessos").SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == obj.Id || x.Descricao.ToLower() == obj.Descricao.ToLower());
            if (rec != null) {
                rec.Acessos.RemoveAll(x => x.ControleId == rec.Id);
            }
            else {
                repository.Grupos.Add(obj);
            }
            repository.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Listar");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Ocorreu um erro enquanto processávamos sua requisição");
            System.Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }

    ViewBag.Controllers = repository.Controles.Include("Acoes").ToList();
    ViewBag.Checkeds = checkeds;

    return View("Cadastro", obj);
}
```

O parâmetro `checkeds`:

[image: checkeds]

O parâmetro **checkeds** vêm com a lista de **on's**.

Então o que eu peço é a ajuda de vocês para elaborar essa View e fazê-la trocar informações corretamente com meu método Action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para postar um array de elementos para a Controller transparentemente, você deve indexar a propriedade `name` para cada um dos checkboxes.

Você deve passar para a Controller cada elemento, para ter o ID e o status de Checked de cada um.

Também está errado escrever a tag `text` dentro da tag `input`, somente deixe "checked".

Eu escreveria algo assim (nomeei aleatoriamente, mas serve como exemplo):

View:

```c-sharp
@{
    var checkedIDs = new int[] { };
    if (ViewBag.Checkeds != null) {
        checkedIDs = ViewBag.Checkeds as int[];
    }
}

...

var checkedIndice = "acoes[" + X + "]";
<input type="hidden" name="@(checkedIndice + ".Key")" id="@(checkedIndice + ".Key")" />
<input type="checkbox" name="@(checkedIndice + ".Value")" id="@(checkedIndice + ".Value")" 
       @(checkedIDs.Contains(acao.Id)? "checked": "") />
```

Controller:

```c-sharp
    public ActionResult Gravar([Bind(Exclude = "Acessos, Usuarios")]Domain.Grupo obj, Dictionary<int, bool> acoes)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                // carrego o grupo caso ele já exista
                ...

                // instancia as tabela de ações marcadas do controle (antes das novas alterações)
                var repAcoes = repository.Acessos.Where(x => x.ControleId == obj.Id);

                // Remove as desmarcadas
                repAcoes.RemoveAll(x => !acoes.ContainsKey(x.AcaoId));

                // adiciona as marcadas que não estavam marcadas
                foreach(var acao in acoes.Where(x => x.Value)){
                    var novaAcao = new Acao(){
                        ControleId = obj.Id,
                        AcaoId = acao.Key
                    };
                    repAcoes.Add(novaAcao);
                }

                repository.SaveChanges();
            ...
    }
```

Comment: Olá @AndreFigueiredo, obrigado pela ajuda. Indexei, só que estou recebendo no array todos os índices com o valor "0", em vez do **Id** da **Acao**. Sabe o que poderia ser?

Comment: Se eu continuar deixando o parâmetro como **string[]** na minha `Action`, o array então continua vindo com a lista de **on's**, se mudo para **int[]** retorna o array com tudo **0**. Então aparentemente está apenas retornado um "positivo" (true) para os índices selecionados.

Comment: Ah, você tem que retornar então um tipo complexo (uma ViewModel para) ou um dicionário Key : Id da Ação, Value: status checado.

Comment: eita.. consegue me dar um exemplo meu caro? por favor!

Comment: Atualizei a resposta, você teria que modificar os itens. Mas no geral seria algo nesse esquema..

Comment: O ASP.NET MVC corta quando a sequência não está completa.. assim: Se você olhar na imagem de exemplo da tela vai entender. Eu selecionei **Listar**, **Adicionar**, pulei o **Alterar** e adicionei o **Excluir** e o **Relatorio** para o **Bairro**. Mas minha `Dictionary` vem apenas com o **Listar** e o **Adicionar**. Mas obrigado, acho que estou entendo isso e vou fazer uns testes. Obrigado!

Comment: sim.. se os inputs tiverem uma sequencia [0, 1, 3], exemplo, o framework irá cortar entre o 1 e 3. Tem que tomar cuidado para ao dar o POST os elementos estarem em sequência (no exemplo, tentei usando o contador X)

Comment: Legal, posso tentar manipular isso com JavaScript/jQuery. Vou tentar!

Answer (score 2):

Bom, resolvi dessa forma que ficou muito mais simples para manipular:

```razor
@{
    var checkeds = new int[] { };
    if (ViewBag.Checkeds != null)
    {
        checkeds = ViewBag.Checkeds as int[];
    }
}
...
<td class="text-center actions" style="width:50px; padding:0; vertical-align:middle;">
    <input type="hidden" name="actions[@X].Key" id="actions[@X].Key" value="@action.Id" />
    <input type="hidden" name="actions[@X].Value" id="actions[@X].Value" value="False" class="value" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[@X]" id="check[@X]"
            @(checkeds.Contains(action.Id) ? "checked" : "") />
</td>
```

com um **jQuery** para ajudar a confirmar qual está selecionado:

```javascript
$("#formGrupoCadastro").submit(function () {
    $(".actions").each(function () {
        var $checkbox = $(this).find("input[type=checkbox]");
        var $hidden = $(this).find("input[type=hidden].value");
        if ($checkbox.is(':checked')) {
            $hidden.attr("value", "True");
        }
    });
});
```

Por fim, em minha **Action**:

```c-sharp
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Gravar([Bind(Exclude = "Acessos, Usuarios")]Domain.Grupo obj, Dictionary<int, bool> acoes)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ...
    }
    ViewBag.Controles = repository.Controles .Include("Acoes").ToList();
    ViewBag.Checkeds = acoes.Select(x => x.Key).ToArray();
    return View("Cadastro", obj);
}
```

Dessa forma passei a ter uma lista completa e muito mais fácil de manusear:

[image: Exemplo do Estado da Dictionary]